# Java servlets - HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET/POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have created a form:

```
  <form method="post" action="new">
      <input type="text" name="title" />
      <input type="text" name="description" />
      <input type="text" name="released" />

      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

When I send this form, I will get following error:

```
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
```

I changed in the form `post` to `get`, but I got a similar error:

Here's how look like the servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String title = request.getParameter("title");
    String description = request.getParameter("description");
    String released_string = request.getParameter("released");
    int released = Integer.parseInt(released_string);
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/app_name", "username", "password");
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into movies values(?, ?, ?)");

        ps.setString(1, title);
        ps.setString(2, description);
        ps.setString(3, released_string);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();    
    } catch(Exception se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I am newbie in Java, but what am I missing in this example? Changing the method how the form is sent out didn't work out...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The entry point of any [`Servlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) is the [`service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) method. [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) implements this method and delegates to one of its [`doGet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29), [`doPost`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29), etc. method based on the HTTP method.

You need to override either `service()` or the approriate `doXxx()` methods. **Your `processRequest` method serves no purpose right now.**

Comment: Depending on the `servlet`'s setup in `web.xml`, it might not being called at all.

Comment: Yeah. I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

you need to override the `doPost()` method and call your `processRequest()` inside it.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
```